# How to create basic lighting for presentation images

Tags: rendering, light, lighting

I just finished my 3d model and I want to sell it. I want to light my scene to make the presentation images. What I want to say, is better to  use a HDRI or lamps for this kind of renders? (presentation images) I want to show my model in the best way.
(I created a small object-a pickaxe and textured it with PBR textures)

I watched a few tutorials and all were focusing on creating an artistic look. I want just to show my model as it really looks.

Comment: Studio lighting HDRIs + a neutral diffuse backdrop model are probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDRI is the best option if you just want to present objects. you can also use Lookdev mode in Blender 2.8 for fast previewing.